# Left aligning text in print statements

Tags: java, java-7

I have a list of keys and values and I would like to print them so the values are left aligned with one another. So for instance if my map is: `{(key9, val9), (key10, val10)}` I want to print it as:

```
key9:  val9
key10: val10
```

My current solution is pretty ugly:

```
int maxKeyLength = findMaxKeyLength(myMap);
for (String key : myMap.keySet()) {
  int numSpaces = maxKeyLength - key.size() + 1;
  // TODO: use StringBuilder instead.
  String toPrint = key + ":";
  for (int i = 0;i < numSpaces;++i) {
    toPrint += " ";
  }
  toPrint += myMap.get(key);
  print(toPrint);
}
```

This works but is a bit ugly. My question is, is there any better way to do this?

Comment: That's fine solution, isn't it?

Comment: It works as I said, but there's gotta to be a better solution that doesn't require nested for loops and 10 lines of code. Maybe some magic escape character or library function.

Comment: @BenjyKessler to avoid nested loops and make your code look simplier you may create `align` function and use it, but that can't be helped much.

Comment: The answer I linked should do the trick with the `printf` method.

Comment: The question, my question is a duplicate of is what I was looking for. I knew there had to be some printf magic that would work.

Comment: You can try String.format().

Answer (score 0):

You could try formatted strings, like so

```
for (String key : myMap.keySet()) {
   System.out.printf( "%-9s %-15s %n", key+":", myMap.get(key));
}
```

[reference](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html)